# Problems with the_time,the_date, get_the_time

Tags: date-time

I have som problems with the date functions in wordpress.

I am trying to get different format on the post date on some pages and i have been trying "the_date()","the_time()" and "echo get_the_date()". They all behave in the same way.

They output the correct date format when i just type for example the_time(). The output is the format i had setup in wordpress settings, as expected.

The problems is that when i try to format the output by ex: the_time('d') the output is "d" or echo get_the_time('F j, Y'); the output is "'F j, Y'".

I forgot to mention that the code is inside "the loop"

This is my page.php

```
<?php get_header();?>
<?php get_sidebar('subnav');?>
<section class="main-content2" id="page">
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<h1><?php the_title();?></h1>
<?php the_content();?>
<footer class="meta">Publicerades den <?php echo get_the_date('d');?></footer>

<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
</section>
<?php get_footer();?>
```

I cannot understand what the problem is, please help!:)

Comment: It should work, I guess. I don't see anything wrong with your code. Disable all plugins and check if this error still exists. Maybe some plugin is breaking things up.

Answer (score 1):

When using date function it is recommanded to use date format or time format of the installation :

```
get_option('time_format');
get_option('date_format');
```

This allows you to grab date format or time format of the current installation.

Comment: I guess Hiren knows that, but he want's to get different date format on some of pages. You can't do it with date format option.

Comment: ok, I see. In this case this should work.

Comment: I have no problem getting the standard format. The problem occurs when trying to get a different date format.

Comment: The problem is now solved. The problem was with qtranslate, which was setup to use strftime instead of date.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Use emulated date function]

You need to choose "Use emulated date function.", not "Use strftime instead of date"

Answer (score 0):

The main reason why `the_time` not working is that you are inputting date formats(`05/01/2015`) in `the_time`, which is specifically for time (`5:00 pm`).